# Excel: countIFS specific day of the week and additional criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering what would be a formula if I want to count based on various criteria, but specifically(because I think this is what I'm having trouble) if one of those criteria should be if a date of a column equals certain day of the week (i.e. 2/2/2016 = thursday)

So basically I want to count how many orders were made on a THURSDAY with the code FTN and with any status except ABANDONED (see image attachments)

Here is the formula I used which gave me 0 when the answer should be 5:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A15,WEEKDAY(A2:A15)=5,C2:C15,"FTN",D2:D15,"<>*ABANDONED*")
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkoVO.png)

[Dates to day of week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tacI2.png)

Comment: Your dates in the data have a little error flag next to them. Are they definitely formatted as dates or is the error flag asking if you want to convert them to dates?

Comment: It is unclear to me what applying WEEKDAY() to a range of cells would do, but it seems to be the problem in your formula. Normally WEEKDAY() is applied to a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIFS() is picky on how the criteria is done, you will not be able to do it this way.  You will need to use an array type formula.

You can use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A2:A15)=5)*(C2:C15="FTN")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ABANDONED",D2:D15))))
```

This will count where all three are True.